# How to set Max-Length in Input tag type is Number?

Tags: html, input

How to set the max-length value in input tag when type is number?

```html
<html>
<body>
<input type="number" maxlength="10">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to MDN:

For [maxLength](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-maxlength)

> Valid for text, search, url, tel, email, and password, it defines the maximum number >of characters (as UTF-16 code units) the user can enter into the field. This must be >an integer value 0 or higher. If no maxlength is specified, or an invalid value is >specified, the field has no maximum length. This value must also be greater than or >equal to the value of minlength.

So `type=number` is ignored. Here is a work around using the pattern

```html
<input type="text" pattern="\d*" maxlength="4">
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h2>JavaScript Validation</h2>

  <p>Enter a number and click OK:</p>

  <input id="id1" type="number" min="100" max="300" required>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">OK</button>

  <p>If the number is less than 100 or greater than 300, an error message will be displayed.</p>

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      const inpObj = document.getElementById("id1");
      if (!inpObj.checkValidity()) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = inpObj.validationMessage;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Input OK";
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.